# How will the ray refract if it passes through the optical axis upwards?

Tags: geometric-optics

I actually want to know in which of either sides it will deviate or what outcome and also for the case when the ray touches the tip of the lens

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) Please consider adding details to the question - as it is of now, at least I do have problems understanding the exact setup you are imagining

Comment: Was there a figure you forgot to add??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to Snell's law of refraction, you should notice that if the angle of incidence is zero, the angle of refraction is also zero. Therefore, there is no deviation in either direction, and the ray continues straight through the material.